# JavaScript convert a users input

Tags: javascript, input, converters

I'm currently in the process of creating a javascript converter to change a users input to morse code.

I have this partially working - see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andythomas123/2c8hwm6u/)

I'm a relative beginner when it comes to javaScript (hence this project to try and improve). I've become stuck trying to remove the input word after the translate. e.g. the result for "hello" would be: 
"HELLO. . . .  .  . - . .  . - . .  - - -  "

I've also put my function below (I've left out the array of letters).

```
function encode() {


document.morsecode.letters.value = document.morsecode.letters.value.replace(/ /g," / ").toUpperCase();

var letters = document.morsecode.letters.value.split("");

for (i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {

    if (letters[i] != " ") {

        if (window.letterCodes[letters[i]]) {

            document.morsecode.letters.value += letterCodes[letters[i]] + "  ";

        } 
    }
}
document.morsecode.letters.value

}
```

If anybody also has any tips on how I could improve this, it would be massively appreciated!

Comment: It would be better if you would create the encoded string in a variable first;

Comment: a perfectly legitimate, nicely formatted question from a beginner that also shows effort and it still get's downvoted - some people are sad

Comment: Thanks guys. I tried to get it as accurate as possible Nicholas, but never mind.

Comment: You should put questions seeking comments on *working* code on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate your encoded string in a new variable, and replace the textarea value when it's done:

```
function encode() {

    var letters = document.morsecode.letters.value.replace(/ /g," / ").toUpperCase();
    var converted_text = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
        if (window.letterCodes[letters[i]]) {
            converted_text += letterCodes[letters[i]] + "  ";
        }
    }
    document.morsecode.letters.value = converted_text;

}
```

Comment: Thanks Johan, this works perfectly! And even more so I completely understand what you've done, so thanks even more for helping me learn!

Answer (score 1):

That's a nice app to learn Javascript.

I would write your code at some points differently:

1. I would store the morse code in a JS object or in an array and create a map from it. The map is in the demo. It creates a JS object same style as below. If you'd prefer the JS object you could also write it like this (you've used a JS object but you've defined it in an unusual way):

   ```
   var letterCodes = {
       A: '. -',   
       B: '- . . .',
       ... };
   ```
2. Use more variables because it's easier to read.
3. Use closures / anonymous function `(function () { ... } )();` to avoid storing stuff in global scope. To learn more about closures search for it at SO.
4. Check out object oriented programming but that's probably the next step, after you've learned the basics.

You can find my code also at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/97w9hpc5/).

```js
(function () {

    var letterCodes = [
        ". -", // code for A
        "- . . .",
        "- . - .",
        "- . .",
        ".", // E
        ". . - .",
        "- - .",
        ". . . .",
        ". .",
        ". - - -",
        "- . -",
        ". - . .",
        "- -",
        "- .",
        "- - -",
        ". - - .",
        "- - . -",
        ". - .",
        ". . .", // S
        "-", // T
        ". . -",
        ". . . -",
        ". - -",
        "- . . -",
        "- . - -",
        "- - . .", // letter Z
        " / "]; // code for /

    function createMap() {
        var obj = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < letterCodes.length; i++) {
            //console.log(i);
            if (i >= 26) {
                // special char at the end 
                // if you have more chars you should do it differently.
                //console.log(letterCodes[i]);
                obj['/'] = letterCodes[i];
            } else {
                obj[String.fromCharCode(97 + i).toUpperCase()] = letterCodes[i];
            }
        }
        //console.log(obj);
        return obj;
    };

    function encode() {

        var letterMap = createMap(),
            morseCode = '',
            inputText = '',
            letter = '',
            code = '';

        inputText = document.morsecode.letters.value.replace(/ /g, " / ");

        var letters = inputText.split("");
        console.log(letters);
        for (i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {

            //if (letters[i] != " ") { // not needed
            letter = letters[i].toUpperCase();

            if (code = letterMap[letter]) {

                morseCode += code + "  ";

            }
            //}
        }
        console.log(inputText, morseCode);
        document.morsecode.letters.value = inputText + ': ' + morseCode;

    }
    
    window.encode = encode;
})();
```

```html
<div class="input-area">

   <form name="morsecode">

    <textarea name="letters" class="textarea" columns="10" rows="10">Test</textarea>

   </form>

  </div>

  <div class="container">

   <a href="#" class="btn" onClick="encode()">Translate my message to morse code</a>

  </div>
```